# MondoDB filter based on array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have these type of data on a Collection:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6014662b3a38ba4929b602ab"
  },
  "collection": [
    {
      "name": "Facility",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "601466293a38ba4929b602aa"
      },
      "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
      "name": "User",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60021529c02fa2b27e7c1989"
      },
      "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Asset",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6018948fc35a109224439f73"
      },

    },
    {
      "name": "Asset",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "604a734fca10c74d800031db"
      },
      "is_deleted": true
    }
  ],
  "customer": "TestCustomer",
  "is_deleted": false
}
```

And also I have this query

```js
db.getCollection("Collection").aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        '$and': [{
            'collection.name': 'User',
            'collection._id': ObjectId('60021529c02fa2b27e7c1989'),
            'collection.is_deleted': false
        }, {
            'collection.name': 'Asset',
            'collection._id': ObjectId('604a734fca10c74d800031db'),
            'collection.is_deleted': false
        }],
        'customer': 'TestCustomer',
        'is_deleted': false
    }
}])
```

`is_deleted` on `Asset` is true in the database, but I am requesting when the value is `false`.

When this query is executed, is not supposed to return nay data, but it does. I have been trying to resolve this issue but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: Why do you think your query should not return any data?

Comment: @codemonkey Because the requested Asset with _id `604a734fca10c74d800031db` is deleted in the database. I am requesting when both values in the array has `is_deleted` = false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to match elements inside an array, you should use `$elemMatch` instead. Also there is no need for the `$and` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "collection": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "name": "User",
          "_id": ObjectId("60021529c02fa2b27e7c1989"),
          "is_deleted": false
        }
      },
      "collection": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "name": "Asset",
          "_id": ObjectId("604a734fca10c74d800031db"),
          "is_deleted": false
        }
      },
      "customer": "TestCustomer",
      "is_deleted": false
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cdz9TgQ8HNw

Comment: It works like a charm. You saved me a lot of headache. Thank You!

Comment: @aldoblack Glad it helped.